# Using Align widget in the Stack widget without it expanding

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to create a custom widget and it makes use of the `Stack` widget. When I wrap the `Stack`'s children using the `Positined` widget, the stack hugs the children that are not positioned. When I try to use the `Align` widget for more precise placement the stack expands to fill all the available space.

I'm trying to avoid using any widget with a fixed size, i.e. `Container` or `SizedBox`, as the parent for the `Stack` widget.

Is there a way to prevent the stack from filling all the available space or work around this that archives the same result?

I'm trying to position a child to the top center of the `Stack` as an example and this is where I am right now:

Using the `Positined` widget (I have to try multiple time to get  the center position and sometimes its still off):

```
Positioned(
  top: 0,
  left: 80,
  child: child,
);
```

[image]

Using the `Align` widget:

```
Align(
  alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
  child: child,
);
```

[image]

This should be the result using the `Align` widget:

```
Align(
  alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
  child: child,
);
```

[image]

Comment: could you include image of what you try to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

You can set Stack's `alignment` to `topCenter`, Try this:

```
Stack(
    alignment: Alignment.topCenter, // <=== add this
    children: [
      Container(
        color: Colors.grey,
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Row(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, // <=== add this
          children: [
            Container(
              color: Colors.amber,
              height: 30,
              width: 30,
            ),
            Container(
              color: Colors.green,
              height: 30,
              width: 30,
            ),
            Container(
              color: Colors.blue,
              height: 30,
              width: 30,
            ),
            Container(
              color: Colors.yellow,
              height: 30,
              width: 30,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      Container(
        color: Colors.red,
        height: 30,
        width: 30,
      )
    ],
  )
```

**Note**: make sure you set Row's `mainAxisSize` to `min`.

[image]

Comment: @craig_hero I updated my answer with better solution, check it out.

Comment: What do I do when I want to add another widget with an alignment of `centerLeft`